# I need the specifications for iRobot Create 2

Tags: irobot-create

I need the specifications for the Create 2. I need it for research purposes. So I think I'm going to need a high computational computer on board.

Please suggest some nice configuration.

Comment: Are you asking for the [Create2 API](http://www.irobot.com/~/media/MainSite/PDFs/About/STEM/Create/create_2_Open_Interface_Spec.pdf), or a hardware recommendation to put on top of a Roomba?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because finding product specifications, even specifications about a *robot*, isn't a question about *robotics*. Contact the manufacturer.

Comment: Welcome to *robotics* Saim, but I'm afraid that *[shopping questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)* really aren't a good fit for a stack exchange site. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*. Take a look at [ask] and [about] for more information on how stack exchange works, and the [*Robotics* question checklist](http://meta.robotics.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) for details of how to write a good question.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure which specifications you're asking about, but the manual is [here](http://www.irobot.com/~/media/MainSite/PDFs/About/STEM/Create/create_2_Open_Interface_Spec.pdf).

As far as "nice configuration," it really depends on what you're up to. A Raspberry Pi 2 can run ROS reasonably well, and is relatively inexpensive. As a bonus, there's a write-up on how to hook up a Pi [here](http://www.irobot.com/~/media/MainSite/PDFs/About/STEM/Create/RaspberryPi_Tutorial.pdf). You could also use a netbook with the supplied Create 2 to USB cable.

Please note that I am an iRobot employee, but the postings on this site are my own and don't necessarily represent iRobot's positions, strategies, or opinions.